# Проблема с горизонтальным grid layout , при быстром прокручивании исчезают элементы

Tags: android

Всем привет, помогите пожалуйста разобраться с такой ситуацией. При медленном горизонтальном прокручивании элементов списка все отображается нормально , но как только делаю быструю прокрутку вперед и начинаю медленно прокручивать назад - некоторые элементы из списка перестают прорисовываться и на их месте пустые полосы получаются.
Определил что проблема исчезает , если контейнеру , в котором размещена картинка и текст ,  высоту и ширину вместо wrap выставить определенные значения, но мне нужно именно wrap 
Всем спасибо заранее

При нормальном перелистывании вперед :
[image: как должно быть везде]

Когда после быстрого перелистывания вперед начинаю перелистывать назад:
[image: как получается]

Класс адаптера:

```
   @NonNull
@Override
public ChannelsRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.card_channel_item_grid, parent, false);
    ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(view);
    holder.rlChannel.setOnClickListener(v -> processChannelItemClick(holder.getAdapterPosition()));
    holder.rlChannel.setOnLongClickListener(v -> {
        processChannelItemLongClick(holder.getAdapterPosition());
        return true;
    });
    return holder;
}

 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.channelNameTv.setText(channelList.get(position).getName());
        GlideApp.with(holder.ivChannel.getContext())
                .load(NetworkConstants.SERVER_LOGO_IMAGE + channelList.get(position).getId() + ".png")
               .apply(RequestOptions.diskCacheStrategyOf(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL))
              .apply(RequestOptions.placeholderOf(R.drawable.ic_image_defaul_channel_image))
                .error(R.drawable.ic_image_defaul_channel_image)
                .into(holder.ivChannel);

        if (type == 0) {
            holder.channelNameTv.setTextColor(holder.channelNameTv.getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.textPrimaryColor));
        } else {
            holder.channelNameTv.setTextColor(holder.channelNameTv.getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.colorIcons));


}
```

Инициализация адаптера :

```
  @Override
public void initRecycler(List<Channel> channels) {
    channelsRecyclerAdapter = new ChannelsRecyclerAdapter(channels);
    channelsRecyclerAdapter.setChannelsRecyclerAdapterListener(this);
    channelsRecyclerAdapter.setType(1);
    GridLayoutManager glm = new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), getGridSpanCounts(), GridLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(glm);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(null);
    recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(channelsRecyclerAdapter);
```

Разметка фрагмента :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_genreName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_s"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_s"
    android:textColor="@color/colorIcons"
    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/devider"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/channel_genre_horizontal_devider"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/tv_genreName"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_s"
    android:background="@color/colorIcons" />

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/devider"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Разметка элемента в рециклере:

```
 <RelativeLayout 
android:id="@+id/rlChannel"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin"
app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/margin_xxs"
app:cardElevation="@dimen/margin_xxxs">


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_chennel"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/margin_xxl"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/margin_xxl"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/channel_logo"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_channel_name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/iv_chennel"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:maxLines="2"
    android:maxLength="13"
    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_s" />

  </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо, я разобрался. Проблема была в высоте рециклера , который в фрагменте размещен. Высота была wrap. Как только поставил `match_parrent` -  элементы списка перестали исчезать. Видимо рециклер автоматически не мог подобрать нужную высоту при прокрутке быстрой и резал элементы